# unable to get other fileds in jquery when using php loops

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
while(...){ ?>
<form>
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo id; ?>" class="myid" />
   <input type="submit"  class="sub" />
<form>
<?php } ?>
```

**jquery**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.sub', function(){
     event.preventDefault(); 
     var myid= $(".myid").val();

     alert(myid);
   });
 });
```

so when when i click submit all i get in return is the first id 
but i would like to alert out the id of the one that i clicked
so the alert should show the value of the textfield when clicked on the appropriate button

Comment: you want to alert out the id of the textfield?

Comment: nope the value inside the textfield

Comment: You should review event handlers in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/on/. You can use $(this) to get the element matching the selector where the click event is being delivered (the ".sub" buttons). You can add additional code to select its sibling input.

Comment: you will have multiple forms tags or a single tags?

Comment: @suzan multiple

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) `.myid` from the button:

```
while(...){ ?>
<form>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="myid" />
    <input type="submit"  class="sub" />
</form>
<?php } ?>


$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.sub', function(){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var myid= $(this).siblings(".myid").val();
    alert(myid);
  });
});
```

`siblings()` will search the DOM tree at the same level of the target element.

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: bro it still says undefined even with siblings

Comment: @c5564200 review your code. is it missing a `$` in `echo id` as is in your question ?

Comment: Also there is a typo, not closing the `<form>` tag. I've edited with a functional code.

Comment: no its not missing anything its actually the same code weird :(

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the event parameter on click function. From there you will have an access to its previous element and then its value

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click","input[type=submit]",function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log($(event.target).prev().val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="text" value="my text value" class="myid" />
   <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit"/>
<form>

<form>
   <input type="text" value="my text value 2" class="myid" />
   <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit"/>
<form>

<form>
   <input type="text" value="my text value 3" class="myid" />
   <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit"/>
<form>
```